# How do I force keywords to automatically capitalize in the VIM editor?

Tags: vim, syntax, editor

Does anybody know how to edit a syntax file for VIM so that keywords are capitalized automatically? I need to do this to keep my coding style consistent with the rest of the developers in my team.

I'm using VIm version 7.2 (actually gVIM) and the syntax file I'm using is the Progress.vim file (installed automatically with VIM under the Syntax directory). I have made a couple tweaks to the file as I didn't like how some things were done, but it is mostly the same.

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
:help abbreviations
```

For example:

```
:iab begin BEGIN
```

Now whenever you type "begin", it will be replaced by "BEGIN".

Comment: Will I need to do this for every keyword, or is there some sort of way to do this for anything classified as a ProgressReserved (i.e. syn keyword ProgressReserved, which would be a list of reserved keywords for the Progress language)?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to automatically do this for a set of keywords. The abbreviation functionality is a generic text replacement facility. It should be easy enough to write a script to generate a vim source file with all your keywords  which you can read in with :source.

Comment: Ok I'll try something along these lines and see how it goes. Thanks Greg.

Comment: you should be able to find that list of keywords in the syntax file in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/progress.vim so you can copy paste from there.

Comment: What do you guys think about using a dictionary file and using CTRL-P (just read about how this can be done)?

Comment: This has the undesirable side-effect that keywords are capitalized also when they appear in comments. I tried this in a Fortran project, and the docstrings I write now looks like this: `INCLUDE extra element and USE L'Hôpital's rule IF x=0`.

Comment: There is also some weird stuff that happens with the word `THEN` at the end of a line if you try to expand the abbreviation and move to a newline simultaneously. I think a linter may be a better option frankly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add to it. The accepted answer is good, but it doesn't say how to constrain it to only `sql` files. @sigvaldm's comment underneath shows that some people may not know how to do that.

To do it in vim, you set up an autocommand:

```
 augroup sqlite
     autocmd!
     au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sql iab abort ABORT
     au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sql iab autoincrement AUTOINCREMENT
 augroup END
```

What this does is that whenever you open any file with a `.sql` on the end of it, it'll do the abbreviations. I got a reserved word list of `sqlite` keywords online, this is the link I used but it could be dead so just search it up: https://github.com/AnanthaRajuC/Reserved-Key-Words-list-of-various-programming-languages/blob/master/language-files/SQLite%20Reserved%20Keywords.md

Then I copy-pasted it into the buffer and set up a macro to write abbreviations for all the keywords. It works really well. If you wish to learn more about autocommands:

`:help autocmd`